# Angular 1 - parsing an $http response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Javascript and Angular. I am trying to move from an $httpbackend mock server using straight JSON data from a file like  [{"firstName":"James",...}...] to getting the data from a live REST server to try out my client code (backand).

On my client I use the http service as follows:

```
return $http.get(serviceUrlBase).then(getAllcontactsSuccess, getAllcontactsError);
// Promises
function getAllcontactsSuccess(response)
{
  return response.data.data;
}

The 'response data.data' returns this:
{"data":[{"__metadata":{"id":"1"},"id":1,"firstName":"James","lastName":"Bud","email":"jbud@gmail.com","phone":"504-621-8927","street":"6649 N Blue Gum St","city":"New Orleans","state":"LA","zip":"70116"},{"__metadata":{"id":"2"},"id":2,"firstName":"Josephine","lastName":"Darakjy","email":"josephine_darakjy@darakjy.org","phone":"810-374-9840","street":"4 B Blue Ridge Blvd","city":"Brighton","state":"MI","zip":"48116"},...]}
```

I read a lot of similar questions and I am trying to write an httptransformer but whatever I try is not working. I cant get rid of the "__metadata":{"id":"1"}, section which seem to be the issue as it is seen as a additional field when carrier over in the controller.

Any ideas is appreciated.

Comment: just strip out the `__metadata` in the service call?

Comment: Why do you need to get rid of it? What problem is it causing? can't you just... not use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you should mock the data to be the same as the actual service call, but in the service call, you can do something like:

```
data = response.data.data
data.forEach(function (d) {
  delete d.__metadata
})
```

Comment: good question, I mean I've said some pretty dumb shit on S.O., but I feel like this was fairly reasonable :)

Comment: This does work. Feels too simple. I was lost in http transformers. I cannot understand why the metadata are not screened out of the angular response. i need to do this becasue  my view code                     <th ng-repeat="(key,value) in ctrl.contacts[0]">{{key}}</th> was messed up in taking the __metadata as a key.  Coming from C++ the delete keyword is something you have to be very careful using

Comment: transformers are for global transformations, i.e. for every single request that comes through. If all of them have `__metadata` you could use the transformations.